# Is it possible to delete a marker 10 seconds after it's placed on map automatically?

Tags: android

I hope to add multiple markers to Google Map and have each one of them deleted permanently and automatically exactly 2 seconds after the marker is added. I saw someone suggesting to use PostDelayed for making marker blink. I would like to know if it's possible to do this for making them disappearing.

In addition to that, if this method actually works, will it be able to handle a large number of markers? If each PostDelayed creates one thread, I'm afraid that after a certain number of markers the performance would be severely slowed.

Please give me some advice on it. Thanks!

Comment: Use postdelayed with one handler, and multiple runnables. No need for separate threads.

Answer (score 1):

**Show marker**

```
Marker restuarantMarkers = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latlng)
                .title("MyPlace").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_pin)).draggable(true));
```

**Hide marker**

```
restuarantMarkers.setVisible(false);
```

**Use handler like that to hide marker**

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        // hide marker after 1000 millies means 1sec
      }
    }, 1000);
```

Hope these helps you.

Comment: Just to be clear, inside run(), I need to implement either the hide or remove function for markers right??

Comment: yes, you are right. please tell me if it works for you.

Comment: I haven't actually implemented anything yet. But when I do I will update you with the result. Thank you!

Comment: I hope it helps you.